# Syncing directorys between two Ubuntu 16.04 LTS servers across WAN VPN

Tags: sync, rsync, grsync

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS server on the West coast. We just purchased another one for the East coast. We have a persistent VPN tunnel between the two sites.

What would be the best way to get two Ubuntu servers to sync a directory? We'll be sync'ing the /home directory. We have Windows servers running DFS for the Windows stuff, but I'm not sure what to use for Ubuntu/Linux.

Rsync? Any good articles I could follow (that are actually up-to-date)?

Existing server: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

New server: Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS

Thanks!

Comment: You can use rsync or some application based on that (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync); there is also an external link to the official website and one to more examples). If you want to sync folders which are modified from both sides, take a look at [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Comment: And now I remember hearing the word Unison many times. I believe that was being used in a previous scenario at this company. I'll start with Unison, as directories on both sides will be modified on a daily basis. Many thanks. Other suggestions still welcomed.